# Как вывести изображение на страницу API Мой Склад

Tags: php, curl, мойсклад-api

Отправляю запрос через cURL

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.2/download/08a4f6ca-1890-46ae-9d8f-bd047bc411d0',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{"query":"","variables":{}}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-type: image/jpeg',
    'Authorization: Basic данные авторизации',
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

echo $response;
curl_close($curl);
```

вместо картинки выводится
����JFIF��C       "" $(4,$&1'-=-157:::#+?D?8C49:7��C  7%%77777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777���"��

вар дамп выдаёт что в response строка. Через библиотеку GD удалось преобразовать текст в картинку, но какой-то оч сложный путь вывода изображения получается. Перерыл всё, но пока решения не нашёл. Менял на разные значения тип контента ***'Content-type: image/jpeg',***

В итоге мне надо получить картинку для вывода в коде html `<img src="" alt="">`
Подскажите кто знает в чём затык.